# How to find and combine Python lists with partial information into single list in large dataset

Tags: python, sql, list, csv

I am reading rows from a CSV file and creating a list of lists, containing all the rows. Finally I send the list of list to a MySQL database. There are about 1.5M rows in the CSV file. The whole process takes about a minute and a half, which is no problem, nor is the size of the list of lists. Below is an example extract from the CSV file, simplified as there are more columns in reality:

```
['AIDS mortality - Females', 'Rate', 'Females estimate', 'All countries', '03M49WLD', 1994, 0.110264]
['AIDS mortality - Females', 'Rate', 'Females upper estimate', 'All countries', '03M49WLD', 1994, 0.120264]
['HIV Incidence - males 15-24', 'Rate', 'Males (15-24)', 'upper estimate', 'Patigi', 'NGA_3_396', 2019, 0.00068]
['AIDS mortality - Females', 'Rate', 'Females lower estimate', 'All countries', '03M49WLD', 1994, 0.100264]
...
```

The challenge is that I need to get the *estimate*, *upper estimate* and *lower estimate* values for a given "indicator" (the first value) into a **single** list so that they end up on the same row in the database. In this example, the three rows with `AIDS mortality - Females`. The database table has columns for estimate/lower/upper **on each row**. Meaning I will end up with only a third as many rows in the database as there were in the original CSV file.

To complicate matters, I can not make any assumptions about where in the CSV file the three corresponding rows (estimate/upper/lower) can be found. Here they are together for illustration, but in reality they can a million rows apart.

I have tried brute-forcing the problem, so for each new row read from the CSV file, scan all lists to see if the all other values are the same, except for the estimate/upper estimate/lower estimate. If so, merge, if not, create new list. This is however very inefficient and takes way too long.

I feel like there is a trick here that a more experienced developer would know to optimize this process.

Comment: can you provide the expected output for this example? it will clarify the desired output

Comment: Load the data into a table with the relevant columns and then just use a query to generate the structure that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That was one approach I tried, but with 1.5M rows it just ran forever. Paul's answer using dicts is probably the more optimal answer.

Comment: @olesk . . . Shouldn't be.  Doing the work in the database should be faster -- but that requires setting up the data correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood the problem correctly, it seems like you'll want to construct a dictionary for each "indicator", which maps the estimates for that indicator to their corresponding values.

```
rows = [
    ['AIDS mortality - Females', 'Rate', 'Females estimate', 'All countries', '03M49WLD', 1994, 0.110264],
    ['AIDS mortality - Females', 'Rate', 'Females upper estimate', 'All countries', '03M49WLD', 1994, 0.120264],
    ['HIV Incidence - males 15-24', 'Rate', 'Males (15-24)', 'upper estimate', 'Patigi', 'NGA_3_396', 2019, 0.00068],
    ['AIDS mortality - Females', 'Rate', 'Females lower estimate', 'All countries', '03M49WLD', 1994, 0.100264]
]

indicator = {}

for row in rows:
    if row[0] not in indicator:
        indicator[row[0]] = {}
    indicator[row[0]][row[2]] = row[-1]

for key, value in indicator.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Output:

```
AIDS mortality - Females {'Females estimate': 0.110264, 'Females upper estimate': 0.120264, 'Females lower estimate': 0.100264}
HIV Incidence - males 15-24 {'Males (15-24)': 0.00068}
```

EDIT - just noticed that the third row in your example data has 8 columns, while the others have 7. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Also, I'd have thought "HIV Incidence - males 15-24" should have "upper estimate": 0.00068. If you don't have a consistently constructed dataset, it's going to be quite a pain to write a program to process it.

Comment: Going via a dictionary might actually do the trick! I feel a bit silly for not thinking about that myself, but I was so struck on a solution with lists.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Sorry, my mistake, I was trying to make a simplified example dataset, as the real one has a lot more columns. All rows have the same number of columns.